# Wordpress SQL query: get random child page

Tags: sql, wordpress

I want my site to have a random "welcome" page.

I've found a plugin that redirects to a random page. I want to specify a parent page that random child pages are selected from.

This is the query that the plug-in uses:

`$query = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'page' AND post_password = '' AND  post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";`

How would I get it to return a random child page from a specific parent page?

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

So simple I missed it. 
Just add `AND post_parent='42'` where *42* is your parent's ID.